# bad base64 error during decrypting on AES

Tags: java, android, encryption, base64, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt some text using AES algorithm like :

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String MODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";


public String encrypt(String value, String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(key.getBytes()));
    byte[] values = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    return Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.URL_SAFE);
}

public String decrypt(String value, String key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    byte[] values = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(key.getBytes()));
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(values));
}
```

The encrypting code works perfectly fine but when I'm trying to decrypt the encrypted text it returns a **bad base64** error.

What I **tried to do before**:

I already tried to **change **Base64.*DEFAULT*** to **Base64.*URL_SAFE***** but it gave me the same error.

Also, I tried to **replace "**/**" and "**+**" with "**_**" and "**-**"** and it doesn't work either.

Heres the value I'm encrypted and trying to decrypt:

**Ssg2w+dv7es7/wWAeAcoAOSVnYKsoLlefbmS8tYr+jc=**

Thanks for helping...

Comment: whats the key you use to encrypt it with? whats the original value? Also, are you sure that code works fine? i m getting error where it cannot resolve your references. `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(values);` `byte[] values = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value);`

Comment: Are you sending the same value as the argument for encrypting and decrypting?

Comment: How do you call them? You should call decrypt ( encrypt ( "original text", "aes key") , " aes key" )

Comment: You generally have to take the same Base64 variant when encoding and decoding (regardless of whether that is the cause of the issue). The posted ciphertext corresponds to e.g. `Base64.DEFAULT`. Btw, that ciphertext doesn't help much without key and IV regarding a repro. I can't reproduce the problem either. Thus, please post a _complete_ example. Also: Taking the key as IV is insecure, and when encoding and decoding the encodings have to be specified, e.g. `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: This might be that there is a hidden character in your ciphertext. Copy it into something that only accepts ASCII, then try again by copying it back again. I had no trouble when copying it from this page anyway.